# Typesetting A* in LaTeX using algorithm2e

Tags: tex, a-star

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126827/typesetting-a-in-latex-using-algorithm2e-follow-up).)

The result looks like

[image]

and my code is:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

  \begin{algorithm}
    \SetKw{Nil}{nil}
    \SetKw{Is}{is}
    \SetKw{Not}{not}
    \SetKw{Mapped}{mapped}
    \SetKw{In}{in}
    \SetKw{ChildNode}{child node}
    \SetKw{Of}{of}
    \SetKw{Continue}{continue}
    $\text{OPEN} = \{ s \}$ \\
    $\text{CLOSED} = \emptyset$ \\
    $\pi = \{ (s \mapsto$ \Nil $)\}$ \\
    $g = \{ (s \mapsto 0) \}$ \\
    \While{$|\text{OPEN}| > 0$}{
      $u = \textsc{ExtractMinimum}(\text{OPEN})$ \\
      \If{$u$ \Is $t$}{
        \KwRet \textsc{TracebackPath}$(u, \pi)$ \\
      }
      $\text{CLOSED} = \text{CLOSED} \cup \{ u \}$ \\
      \ForEach{\ChildNode $v$ \Of $u$}{
        \If{$v \in \textsc{CLOSED}$}{
          \Continue \\
        }
        $c = g(u) + w(u, v)$ \\
        \If{$v$ \Is \Not \Mapped \In $g$}{
          $g(v) = c$ \\
          $\pi(v) = u$ \\
          \textsc{Insert}$(\text{OPEN}, v, c + h(v))$ \\
        }
        \ElseIf{$g(v) > c$}{
          $g(v) = c$ \\
          $\pi(v) = u$ \\
          \textsc{DecreaseKey}$(\text{OPEN}, v, c + h(v))$ \\
        }
      }
    }
    \KwRet $\langle \rangle$
    \caption{\textsc{AStarPathFinder}$(s, t, w, h)$}
  \end{algorithm}

  \begin{algorithm}
    \SetKw{Is}{is}
    \SetKw{Not}{not}
    \SetKw{Nil}{nil}
    $p = \langle \rangle$ \\
    \While{$u$ \Is \Not \Nil}{
      $p = u \circ p$ \\
      $u = \pi(u)$ \\
    }
    \KwRet $p$
  \caption{\textsc{TracebackPath}$(u, \pi)$}
  \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Can I make my code better? For example, is there a way to defined custom keywords in a "global scope" so that I don't have to repeat myself?

Comment: Just define the keywords outside of the algorithm blocks and they will be usable to the end of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing `\textsc` and `\text` all the time, I prefer semantic markup, such as `\func` and `\var`. These simple name changes make the source code easier to read for me. Compare:

```
\var{p} = \func{prime}(\var{x})
\text{p} = \textsc{prime}(\text{x})
```

When reading the first line aloud, you will quickly notice any discrepancy between a name and its type.

It looks weird to me that the math mode is closed before the first `\Nil` and another math mode is opened again immediately after it. This could influence the spacing in subtle ways. It's probably better to write it like this:

```
$\pi = \{ (s \mapsto \text{\Nil})\}$
```

This wording feels more natural since there is really only a single math expression here.

The last `\caption` is not indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me.

As Johannes_B mentioned, hoist (at least three of) the SetKw definitions up to global context, to delete the redundant Is/Not/Nil definitions, and you're done.