# Typesetting A* in LaTeX using algorithm2e - follow-up

Tags: tex, a-star

(See the [previous and initial iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112569/typesetting-a-in-latex-using-algorithm2e).)

I have this second version of my LaTeX code. I made it less dry by removing the duplicate keyword definitions shared by the two algorithms being typeset. Also, in the previous version, in the argument of main **`While`** loop, *`OPEN`* was typeset instead of desired `OPEN`.

See what I have now:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\SetArgSty{textnormal} % Make the While argument non-italic

% Define special keywords.
\SetKw{Nil}{nil}
\SetKw{Is}{is}
\SetKw{Not}{not}
\SetKw{Mapped}{mapped}
\SetKw{In}{in}
\SetKw{ChildNode}{child node}
\SetKw{Of}{of}
\SetKw{Continue}{continue}

\begin{document}

  % A*.
  \begin{algorithm}
        $\text{OPEN} = \{ s \}$ \\
        $\text{CLOSED} = \emptyset$ \\
        $\pi = \{ (s \mapsto$ \Nil $)\}$ \\
        $g = \{ (s \mapsto 0) \}$ \\
        \While{$|\text{OPEN}| > 0$}{
          $u = \textsc{ExtractMinimum}(\text{OPEN})$ \\
          \If{$u$ \Is $t$}{
            \KwRet \textsc{TracebackPath}$(u, \pi)$ \\
          }
          $\text{CLOSED} = \text{CLOSED} \cup \{ u \}$ \\
          \ForEach{\ChildNode $v$ \Of $u$}{
            \If{$v \in \textsc{CLOSED}$}{
              \Continue \\
            }
            $c = g(u) + w(u, v)$ \\
            \If{$v$ \Is \Not \Mapped \In $g$}{
              $g(v) = c$ \\
              $\pi(v) = u$ \\
              \textsc{Insert}$(\text{OPEN}, v, c + h(v))$ \\
            }
            \ElseIf{$g(v) > c$}{
              $g(v) = c$ \\
              $\pi(v) = u$ \\
              \textsc{DecreaseKey}$(\text{OPEN}, v, c + h(v))$ \\
            }
          }
        }
        \KwRet $\langle \rangle$
        \caption{\textsc{AStarPathFinder}$(s, t, w, h)$}
  \end{algorithm}

  % Traceback path.
  \begin{algorithm}
        $p = \langle \rangle$ \\
        \While{$u$ \Is \Not \Nil}{
          $p = u \circ p$ \\
          $u = \pi(u)$ \\
        }
        \KwRet $p$
      \caption{\textsc{TracebackPath}$(u, \pi)$}
  \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: A*]

Any critique is much appreciated.

Comment: I really like the visualization of the blocks

Comment: @MrSmith42 Yes, they are fairly convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice.  I mean if you're going for perfection I'm going to write
something but otherwise that looks really good.

- The
  [documentation for algorithm2e](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf)
  mentions that every line should be terminated with `\;` - and then has
  a flag to disable showing that semicolon, `\DontPrintSemicolon` - take
  that how you will.  At least Emacs highlights that less garishly than
  the forced newline.
- The variables could be marked via `\SetKwData`.  If you want to keep
  the same style, modify it via `\SetDataSty{textnormal}`.  Similarly
  for the functions via `\SetKwFunction`.
- The style for the captions could also just be set to smallcaps
  globally via `\let\AlCapNameSty\textsc` (works and should be correct,
  but I'm not a \$\LaTeX\$ expert by any means.
- Also there's the `procedure` environment (instead of `algorithm`) that
  has some more shortcuts.  Note that I added `procnumbered` and
  `\SetAlgoProcName` to set the names and numbering back to what is the
  default algorithm settings.

Looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,procnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\SetArgSty{textnormal} % Make the While argument non-italic
\SetDataSty{textnormal}
\SetFuncSty{textsc}
\let\AlCapNameSty\textsc
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetAlgoProcName{Algorithm}

% Define special keywords.
\SetKw{Nil}{nil}
\SetKw{Is}{is}
\SetKw{Not}{not}
\SetKw{Mapped}{mapped}
\SetKw{In}{in}
\SetKw{ChildNode}{child node}
\SetKw{Of}{of}
\SetKw{Continue}{continue}

\SetKwData{Open}{OPEN}
\SetKwData{Closed}{CLOSED}

\SetKwFunction{ExtractMinimum}{ExtractMinimum}
\SetKwFunction{TracebackPath}{TracebackPath}
\SetKwFunction{Insert}{Insert}
\SetKwFunction{DecreaseKey}{DecreaseKey}

\begin{document}

% A*.
\begin{procedure}
        $\Open = \{ s \}$ \;
        $\Closed = \emptyset$ \;
        $\pi = \{ (s \mapsto$ \Nil $)\}$ \;
        $g = \{ (s \mapsto 0) \}$ \;
        \While{$|\Open| > 0$}{
        $u = \ExtractMinimum(\Open)$ \;
        \If{$u$ \Is $t$}{
            \KwRet \TracebackPath{$u$, $\pi$} \;
        }
        $\Closed = \Closed \cup \{ u \}$ \;
        \ForEach{\ChildNode $v$ \Of $u$}{
            \If{$v \in \Closed$}{
            \Continue \;
            }
            $c = g(u) + w(u, v)$ \;
            \If{$v$ \Is \Not \Mapped \In $g$}{
            $g(v) = c$ \;
            $\pi(v) = u$ \;
            \Insert{\Open, $v$, $c + h(v)$} \;
            }
            \ElseIf{$g(v) > c$}{
            $g(v) = c$ \;
            $\pi(v) = u$ \;
            \DecreaseKey{\Open, $v$, $c + h(v)$} \;
            }
        }
        }
        \KwRet $\langle \rangle$
        \caption{AStarPathFinder($s$, $t$, $w$, $h$)}
\end{procedure}

% Traceback path.
\begin{procedure}
        $p = \langle \rangle$ \;
        \While{$u$ \Is \Not \Nil}{
        $p = u \circ p$ \;
        $u = \pi(u)$ \;
        }
        \KwRet $p$
    \caption{TracebackPath($u$, $\pi$)}
\end{procedure}

\end{document}
```